# Make ball move to specify direction

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I want to make a ball move to certain direction like I give number from 
0 - 360. Currently my convention is:

0 moves right, 90 down, 180 left and 270 up.

The problem is that if I put something like 10, 11, 12 etc., it doesn't move at all. Some numbers makes it move in 45 angle someway.

My current code:

```
float x = 0, y = 0;
float speed = 1f;

int angle = 90;

float moveX += speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
float moveY += speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));

x += moveX;
y += moveY;

moveX = 0;
moveY = 0;
```

If I take off `toRadians`, the ball goes to different direction, but still doesn't work.

My math and English are terrible so try to explain this simple as possible. And I don't know differences between radians and degrees.

Comment: Ah hint: there are no detours in life. If you want to do math ... then knowing math is essential. Maybe start here: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radians.htm ... that is the nice thing nowadays: just put the terms you need to learn about into your search engine, and typically you will find a ton of material to study ... for free. So please do not expect us to **write** down that kind of basics again ... just for you. (where I am not saying that your question is a bad one; I am just pointing out that you dont need us for the base research).

Comment: I have tried.. I tried to learn about radians and degrees, but I it is so mutch harder in english because I know only plus, minus, multiply, divide.

Comment: Did you try searching the net for material in your language?

Comment: Yes I am currently reading but still dont understand anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know differences between radians and degrees etc.

This is not exactly the site for this, but here's a simple explanation. Radians and degrees are 2 measurement units (like kilometers and miles). A circle has 360 degrees, or 2π radians. That means that

```
1 degree = π/180 (0.0174533) radians
1 radian = 180/π (57.2958) degrees
```

The 4 cardinal directions on the circle using radiands would be 0 or 2π, π/2, π, 3π/2 corresponding to 0 or 360, 90, 180, 270 degrees.

> I want to make ball move to certain direction like I give number from 0 - 360

Now to your code. You have a syntax error in the line

```
float moveX += speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

You just declared `moveX`, so you don't add to it with `+=`, you just assign to it with `=`. Same with `moveY`. Now if you print `x` and `y` after

```
x += moveX;
y += moveY;
```

you will get the right results. I don't know why after that you're setting them to 0 - you will lose the position of the ball.

Comment: Oh sorry that 'float' there was accident I dont have that in my real code. And I am setting moveX and Y to 0 after already adding them to my balls x  and y.

Comment: @Maineri Then next time to avoid this situations post a [mcve]. So di this solve your problem?

Comment: Not rly.. I think I am too simple person to understand this.

Comment: @Maineri Weel, this code does what you described. If you could check that your code didn't work, then you can check if this one does.

Answer (score -2):

Instantiate moveX and moveY before the loop